# What were the ranks of say, the five crewmen of a Panzer in World War II?

Tags: world-war-two, military, nazi-germany

At Normandy, tank ace, [Major Michael Wittmann](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michael_Wittmann) commanded a group of seven tanks. This was probably a unit that had been decimated by casualties. Even so, my understanding is that an officer of Wittmann's rank might command a unit of 9-15 tanks at full strength.

Given the above, what might be the ranks of the five crewman of an individual tank? My guess is that the most senior would be a first or second lieutenant, or at least a senior non-com, the most junior might be a "buck" private, with numbers two, three, and four being of "intermediate" ranks. How close is this guess to actual ranks in known units?

Comment: Hmmm...it seems like I read an answer to this at some point. Might even have been somewhere here.

Comment: You might have been thinking of [this one](https://history.stackexchange.com/q/60723/16951).

Comment: I was writing up an answer specific to Wittman and the 101st Heavy Tank Battalion when the question closed. It illustrates subtitles around independent units and SS ranks vs Wehrmacht. If you want to refocus on Wittmann's rank and chain of command I'd reopen.

Comment: @Schwern: I've been working on another question about Wittmann's chain of command above tank commander. My preference is to complete the new question rather than "resurrect" the earlier one, because of its heavy overlap with the "age" question.

Comment: @TomAu When it's up, tag me and I'll have a look.

Comment: @Schwern: If I were writing an answer to a question that was on the verge of being closed, I would post one line of it as  "placeholder," and delete it. Then I would finish the answer in the "deleted" format and undelete it.