# In the US Army in WWII how long did it typically take for a promotion from private to PFC?

Tags: world-war-two, united-states

In early 1943 how long might it take for an US Army inductee to be promoted from private to PFC?  What were the requirements?

Comment: Surviving combat would seem high on the list of requirements.

Comment: [Documenting preliminary research will improve both the probability of an answer and the quality of the answer(s)](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/a/785/26786)

Comment: Some discussion here  -  https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/60723/what-was-the-average-age-of-tank-crews-in-particular-commanders-in-ww2/60732#60732

Comment: For the 2023 US Army, https://www.army.mil/ranks/ says for a Private "Eligible for promotion to private first class after 4 months time in rank and 12 months time in service." In actual wartime I suspect that gets shortened pretty quickly...

Comment: From https://americansoldierww2.org/topics/assignment-promotion - a graphic shows that as of  May 31, 1945, there were 2.2 million private first class and 1.6 million privates. Also 1.5M corporals, 1.0M sergeants, and some 0.8M higher NCOs, that means a lot of privates were promoted to PFC and beyond in 4 years or so.

Comment: From https://www.army.mil/article/18048/army_nco_history_part_6_world_war_ii - "With the vast amount of casualties suffered in the war, enlisted men rose through the ranks very quickly during World War II. This resulted in a perceived lessening of the prestige of the NCO to some higher enlisted NCOs who obtained their rank prior to the war. Soldiers were quickly promoted from private to corporal; and corporal to sergeant after only serving a small amount of time in the unit" - but, no solid numbers given.